# php exception лог ошибок

Tags: исключения, php

Для каждой группы ошибок, рекомендуют создавать несколько эксепшенов.

В чем трабл:

Возьмем к примеру несколько типов ошибок, fooException, barException, mooException.
Все они наследуются от базового класса exception. У всех них одинаковые методы и их реализация. То есть получается много наследуемых классов с одинаковым содержимым быстро размножающихся в папке с классами ошибок. Это не правильно?

И еще вопрос, все теже 3 класса ошибок, выводятся сообщения ошибок, работают. А теперь как мне все ошибки с 3х классов писать в лог(xml)?

Comment: @ХэшКод А разве можно использовать такие ники, вроде @admin?

Comment: я думал, что есть банальная проверка. Ну раз зарегался, так зарегался :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Да, неправильно. Общее поведение (если точно известно, что оно не будет меняться), следует вынести в базовый класс.
2. Ну отлично. Сделайте интерфейс для сериализации ваших объектов в лог, либо задайте некое общее базовое поведение в базовом классе, содержащем логику сериализации, и наследуйтесь от него.

Comment: был бы признателен за ссылки или примеры

Comment: "object serialization", "object serialization in php", "xml writer php" и т.д....

Comment: Зачем так категорично? С гуглом у меня проблем нет.

Comment: Все равно - спасибо

Comment: > Зачем так категорично? С гуглом у меня проблем нет.

@admin там тоже admin ??

Answer (score 1):

Правильно. Поскольку и**сключения различаются не по поведению, а по именам.** Это несколько непривычная концепция, но *имя* класса исключения означает больше, чем имя любого другого оператора языка. По именам мы исключения перехватываем. То есть, если нам будут нужны разные обработчики для разных исключений, то различать мы их будем по имени. Собственно, это и является той самой причиной, по которой рекомендуется на каждый чих создавать свой своё исключение.

Чтобы вместо `catch (Exception $e)` можно было написать `catch (fooException $e)` и поймать только одну строго определенную ошибку.